# Finding the indices of fixed points of a 2-D system

Tags: nonlinear-system

so while studying non linear dynamics I came across a simple question that I cannot find the solution to anywhere.

Consider the following system:
$$\begin{align} \frac{dx}{dt} &= y + y^{2} \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt}&= \dfrac{-1}{2}x +\dfrac{1}{5}y -xy + \dfrac{6}{5}y^2 \end{align} $$

a) What are the indices of the fixed points and why?

Trying to solve this I computed the fixed points to be $(0,0)$ and $\left(\dfrac{14}{15},1\right)$

using the Jacobian I figured they were both unstable spirals (I think, even though I have difficulty understanding how that is). so how do I compute the indices, I,m not sure what they are and cant find it on the internet. Do they have a role in determining in the fixed points are enclosed by a limit cycle?

Comment: Sorry you're correct I don't know how I obtained $\frac{14}{15}$. I don't know what the indices of a fixed point are and can't find it online so I was hoping it was common terminology that someone could explain. all I know is that I need to know them to determine which of the fixed points is enclosed by a limit cycle, given that the system is known to have at least one limit cycle.

Comment: Would it make sense to apply index theory here in the context of this question?

Comment: That seems to have put me on the right track, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium sets are given by the solutions to

$$
\dot x = y + y^2 = 0\\
\dot y = -\frac x2+\frac y5-x y +\frac 65 y^2 = 0
$$

giving two pints

$$
p_1 = (-2,-1)\\
p_2 = (0,0)
$$

now calculating the jacobians at each poin

$$
J_{p_1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
J_{p_2} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues

$$
J_{p_1} \Rightarrow \left\{-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{7 i}{10},-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{7 i}{10}\right\}\;\;\mbox{sink}\\
J_{p_2} \Rightarrow \left\{\frac{1}{10}+\frac{7 i}{10},\frac{1}{10}-\frac{7 i}{10}\right\}\;\;\mbox{source}
$$

Attached a stream plot showing the phase-plane

[image]